# How to find the following limit which has $e^x$ and $e^{it}$ terms

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The question is to show that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{xe^{\frac{it}{\sqrt x}}}}{e^{x+it\sqrt x}}=e^{-\frac{t^2}2}$$
I am just baffled by $t^2$ on the $RHS$ as that means powers of one of the $e^{it}$ terms on the $LHS$ is squared in the process of finding the limit. For the denominator part, I could do
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{xe^{\frac{it}{\sqrt x}}}}{e^{x+it\sqrt x}} = \frac{e^{xe^{\frac{it}{\sqrt x}}}\cos t\sqrt x-i\sin t\sqrt x}{e^x}$$
but not sure how to go further. A hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Expand $e^{it/\sqrt x}$ in a power series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{xe^{\frac{it}{\sqrt x}}}}{e^{x+it\sqrt x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{xe^{it/\sqrt x}-x-it\sqrt x}$$
Expanding $e^{it/\sqrt x}$ into its Maclaurin series gives
$$xe^{it/\sqrt x}=x\left(1+\frac{it}{\sqrt x}+\frac12\cdot\frac{-t^2}x+\frac16\cdot\frac{-it^3}{x\sqrt x}+\cdots\right)$$
$$=\color{red}{x+it\sqrt x}-\frac{t^2}2-\frac{it^3}{6\sqrt x}+\cdots$$
The first two terms (in red) are cancelled out by $-x-it\sqrt x$. The terms after $-\frac{t^2}2$ vanish in the limit of $x\to\infty$. Thus only $-\frac{t^2}2$ remains, i.e.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{xe^{\frac{it}{\sqrt x}}}}{e^{x+it\sqrt x}}=e^{-t^2/2}$$